# How to create repositories within a repository to manage tracking of different files and folders

Tags: git

Here is the situation

I clone a repository on to my local machine using `git clone <ParentRepository_URL>`, this action copies the repository `ParentRepository` to my local machine and initializes it.

Now I have another separate directory containing files and directories on my local machine called let's say `SubDirectory`. FYI `SubDirectory` is not a git repository, it is just a local directory with some files and other sub-directories in it.

What I wanna do is copying this `SubDirectory` into my `ParentRepository` (`ParentRepository` is already a git repository) but I don't want the files and directories within the `SubDirectory` being tracked by `ParentRepository` (which is a git repo) at the time of copying. When I copy `SubDirectory` in `ParentRepository` then `git` is going to consider `SubDirectory` and its contents as new files and if I use `git add` all the files within `SubDirectory` are going to be tracked, but I don't want this.

Instead I just want the subsequent changes that I make to `SubDirectory` after copying it to `ParentRepository` being tracked and captured.

Some more clarification:

Let's say I run the following command on the terminal on my local machine:

```
git clone <ParentRepository_URL>
```

This clones and initializes a local git repository on my machine, now let's say I run the following command in `ParentRepository_URL` right after cloning:

```
git status
```

This is going to tell me that my branch is clean and nothing to add or commit. Now Let's copy my local directory `SubDirectory` (this is not a git repo) in `ParentRepository_URL`, so I'm going to have `ParentRepository_URL/SubDirectory`, now if I run

```
git status
```

It's going to tell me I have new changes to `add`.
So all I wanna know is that, is there any way for me to tell git to ignore this first phase? There seems to be commands such as `git submodule add` or `git subtree` but I couldn't figure out how to use them to this end.

**What is the solution?**

Comment: Is `SubDirectory` a git repository? You should get a look at [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)

Comment: @Raida , No `SubDirectory` is not a git repository it is just a directory with some files and other sub-directories in it, that's what makes it somehow confusing for me on how to use `git submodule`

Comment: I don't understand "Instead I just want the subsequent changes that I make to SubDirectory after copying it to ParentRepository being tracked and captured." and "if I use git add all the files within SubDirectory are going to be tracked, but I don't want this.". Those statements are contradictory. Do you want to track the files or not?

Comment: Git tracks the _full content of files_. Git does _not_ track "changes". (It seems like there is some confusion about this)

Comment: @knittl , what you are saying is not entirely accurate, git actually takes snapshots of different states of a repository but when you run a command such as `git status` it only shows the changes you made, that's why after cloning a repository and before making any changes to it by running `git status` it tells you that your working directory is clean. This is what I want to see after copying my local directory to my repository, once I copy it to my repository I want git to ignore it as a change and only from that point tracking the changes, like it was a part of original clone.

Comment: @Dude no, what I'm saying is 100% accurate. Yes, Git stores snapshots of the repository (i.e. the _full content_ of all files at a certain point in time). If you run `git status` it will look at the latest snapshot and compare it against your working tree. No previous snapshot of a file == not possible to compare or compute the changes. If you want to see the (uncommitted or unstaged) changes of a file, this file must be tracked already. Git only knows and only cares about the content tracked files

Answer (score 1):

create a .gitignore file
then add the thing you don't want to push in .gitignore file

Comment: This is not necessarily a viable solution, here is why. Because I would only like to initially ignore the files and directories only at the time of copying, but eventually I am going to make changes to them and I need the changes to the existing files to be tracked. So how is this possible?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a submodule. More information available here

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is simply not possible with Git (or any other SCM for that matter). Git either tracks the content of files (meaning that you had to run `git add` at some point), or Git ignores files (meaning that they are not tracked and possibly matched by a pattern in `.gitignore`).

Think about it this way: how [wc]ould Git know about the "changes", if it never knew about the files in the first place? Changes can only be computed – via the diff(erence) mechanism – if you have two versions of the file as input, i.e. the old, unchanged version of the file and the new, changed version of the file.

If it were possible and you only stored the "new" changes, once your files change. How would you (or Git or any other SCM) know what the previous version of the file looked like, in other words what would the changes change?

Let me try to explain it in a different way:

1. Commit A
2. Commit B
3. You copy the files (and leave them untracked/ignored)
4. Commit C
5. You change something in one of your still-untracked/ignored file
6. Commit D – what does it contain? Only the "changes" of the previously-untracked file? The changes as compared to what? What happens if you go back (`git checkout` or `git switch`) to commit C, what would the content of your file be?

(I'm also having a hard time seeing a use case for this)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have reached the same conclusion for the moment. Although I'm still wondering whether I couldn't really convey the message in a more clear way or it is not really possible. I gotta try to understand `git submodule` and `git subtree` in a more substantial way to figure out if they can offer some solution in this context.

Comment: @Dude if it were possible to only store the "new" changes/differences: how would that even work? You don't have a previous version to apply the changes to.